# How to bind an event handler to a button in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua

guys I spent 3 hours trying to debug my code I just couldn't so here I am its in roblox's scripting language lua ok here it is.

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(funtion()
  script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
end)
```

. I just cant understand why it doesn't work this is the code it supposed to be that when you click the play button it takes you to the game but it idint it just showed an error for me.

Comment: I edited your title, when asking questions on Stackoverflow, try and frame your problem as the specific question you are trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo on `script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:connect(funtcion()` First you don't put `script.Parent` you would have to do this

```
yourscriptnamehere.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()

game.Workspace.part.visible = false
end)
```